# Double AES encryption with random key generation

Tags: c++, linux, random, openssl, aes

I am using 2 embedded GSM devices. There needs to send data between devices. Suppose I require to send the string "ring" from one device to another. It is a command and needs to be sent multiple times. 1st thing I do is keep the aes_key same in both devices. Then encrypt the input_data(that is "boom") and get the enc_buffer. Send this enc_buffer over socket to other device. The other device has same aes_key. Using that I decrypt the buffer received into dec_buffer. My doubt is that will the encrypted message enc_buffer be same every time I send the encrypted text for "boom". If it is same, then I need to follow another approach. I have a 1st level aes_key, that is constant. Then I need to generate a 2nd level aes_key. Encrypt the 2nd level aes_key and send it over socket. In the receiving device, decrypt it using 1st level aes_key to get the 2nd level aes_key. Store it. In 1st device again encrypt string "boom" using 2nd level aes_key, send it over socket. In the 2nd device decrypt the encrypted message using 2nd level aes_key to get text "boom". But another problem is how to generate the 2nd level aes_key in 1st device. Is there some random key generator API present in Linux. Or can I use random number generator API. I need a 10 character-length key. For that I call random number generator 10 times to generate a number between 0-26 and convert this to character. Then gather then together to get the desired key.  I am using the AES code sample as below. Pasted for reference to above text.

```
unsigned char aes_key[]= "asytfuhcilejnco";
unsigned char input_data[]= "Sandeep";
int data_size= strlen((char*)input_data);
int buffer_size = ((int)(data_size/AES_BLOCK_SIZE) + 1)*AES_BLOCK_SIZE;

AES_KEY enc_key,dec_key;
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

int main()
{
unsigned char enc_buffer[buffer_size+1];
unsigned char dec_buffer[buffer_size+1];

    memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(input_data,enc_buffer,sizeof(input_data),&enc_key,iv,AES_ENCRYPT);
    enc_buffer[buffer_size+1]='\0';

    memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key,sizeof(aes_key)*8,&dec_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_buffer,dec_buffer,sizeof(input_data),&dec_key,iv,AES_DECRYPT);
    dec_buffer[buffer_size+1]='\0';

    cout<<"input_data="<<input_data<<endl;
    cout<<"enc_buffer="<<enc_buffer<<endl;
    cout<<"dec_buffer="<<dec_buffer<<endl;
}
```

so, I have 3 questions

1. Is encrypted data always the same for same input_data and aes_key?
2. Is there any random key generator API?
3. What systemcall is there for random numbers in Linux c++?

Comment: "Then encrypt the input_data(that is "boom")" your data sounds suspicious

Comment: it is not "boom" but something else

Comment: Yea right, "detonate" or whatever

Comment: What is the purpose of the encryption? And are there three devices involved -- the two GSM embedded devices and the Linux machine? Or are the embedded devices running Linux? Why roll your own solution rather than using something well understood like TLS?

Comment: sorry no need to get suspicious I am not doing anything likethat

Comment: this will be used to alert the user by ringing/stop ringing etc. if there is thresh hold distance separation and more features. So, do not want someone to know  what command we are using.

Comment: You say "I do not know how to use random number generator. Can anyone suggest?" Apart from that the question is a torrent of words.

Comment: Unrelated, you understand that the encrypted blocks will likely contain embedded zero-octets or non-printable values when treated as characters, *right* ? The null-termination management is pointless. That data is simple bytes; not ascii chars, so dumping to your output stream is worthless.

Comment: there are 2 devices only, they may have any OS like linux,ios,android etc

Comment: "I do not know how to use random number generator" - then *please* stay away from cryptography of any kind.

Comment: null termination is not part of the code, I am using AES 1st time, so I was seeing what I get.This is just a sample code

Comment: [`RAND_bytes`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/RAND_bytes.html) is pretty straight forward, and literally self documenting. I would think it likely to accomplish whatever random needs you may have. Don't abuse it, btw.

Comment: Are you sure encryption is actually what you want? Are the messages secret? Is the actual object something else such as authentication? Why not just use SSL/TLS?

Comment: I think the messages should be  secret,it needs to prevent someone from stopping ringing/sending location, distance etc in child theft, object theft etc. I am reading about TLS/SSL

Comment: I am using bluetooth for communication(BT communication is similar to socket communicationas per linux bluezAPIs)

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is encrypted data always the same for same input_data and aes_key?

No. It is the same for the same **key**, **iv**, & **data**.

> Is there any random key generator API?

Yes, OpenSSL has one, for instance.

> What systemcall is there for random numbers in Linux c++?

A "good" random number generator is /dev/urandom. Arguably better, if available, is /dev/hwrng, however it is different, not necessarily better. /dev/random is similar, possibly better to /dev/urandom but will block when sufficient entropy is not available.

In all cases you read these devices just as you would read data from a file.

Answer (score 1):

`enc_buffer[buffer_size+1]='\0'`

Don't do that, this is a buffer overflow. The maximum index on both your buffers is [buffer_size].

`memset(iv,0x00,AES_BLOCK_SIZE);`

Don't do that, using the same iv (Initialization Vector) guarantees that your ciphertext will also be the same. For encryption, initialize the iv with random bits as Claris mentioned. For decryption you can ignore the iv output.